# Actionable Relationship Center Component is not opening

Tags: lightning, profile, permission-sets, financial-services-cloud

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_set_up_arc.htm

I have configured Actionable Relationship Center Component as per above link and assign the ARC permission set some users, some users are able to see this component for some users i am getting the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Financial Service Cloud Standard Permission set to users, who are not able to see this component.